Как мотать строчки в командной строке Linux(Debian) , не имея графического интерфейса
Я хочу поскролить список своих команд, которые я только что написал ,но, при нажатие на стрелочки или PgUp или PgDn лишь выдаётся прошлые команды, при нажатие на те же самые PgUp или PgDn с зажатым Shift также ничего не происходит.вот я написал всякую ересь на фотографии и хочу посмотреть что я писал ранее, подскажите как это сделать, пожалуйста 

Попробуйте все комбинации отсюда: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60382/how-to-scroll-in-a-terminal-using-keyboard. Если не поможет, поставьте screen/tmux, они поддерживают эту функциональность вне зависимости от эмулятора терминала, хотя придётся почитать помощь и пользоваться необычными комбинациями клавиш.

Большое спасибо, сейчас попробую, а то крайне раздражает что впервые установил без графического интерфейса и вот такая проблема

  Советую запустить ssh сервер, подключиться из ОС с графикой через эмулятор терминала, в windows10, cmd уже установлен клиент ssh, в linux тоже имеется эмулятор терминала и ssh клиент.  Появится возможность прокручивать страницы, станет возможно одновременно открыть несколько окон, легко перекидывать файлы, даже на windows без установки samba. Возможно прокидывать порты и тоннели. Копировать и вставлять текст.
